# Roots of irreducible polynomial $1 + x + \cdots + x^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm studying some Galois theory and I'm trying to determine the Galois group of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2 \pi i/5}) \supset \mathbb{Q}.$

We consider the minimal polynomial of the element $e^{2 \pi i/5}$ which is just $x^5-1 =(x-1)(1+x+\cdots+x^4).$  If $(x-1)(1 + x + \cdots + x^4) = 0$ then either $h(x) = (x-1)=0$ or $g(x) = (1+x+\cdots+x^4)=0.$ If $x =e^{2 \pi i/5}$ then clearly $h(x) \ne 0,$ so it must be that case that $g(e^{2 \pi i/5}) = 0$ and hence $e^{2 \pi i/5}$ is a root of $g(x).$ If $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/5}$ then similarly $\omega^2, \omega^3,$ and $\omega^4$ are roots of $g(x).$ Is this reasoning correct so far? Next I will use the fact that automorphisms of the Galois group map roots to roots to show that the Galois group contains $4$ automorphisms $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2 \pi i/5}) \to \mathbb{Q}(e^{2 \pi i/5})$ that keep elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right! But you still need to show that the polynomial $1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4}$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$, (you can shift by 1 and apply Einsesntein criterion, I think you've paid attention to it). So you get a Galois extension of degree 4, and hence has 4 automorphisms. Now as you said, you can find at most 4 automorphisms, and hence you've listed them all!... And, then, it becomes an easier task to find the Galois group!

Comment: I proved that $1 + x + \cdots + x^{p-1}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for all prime $p.$ So the number of elements on the Galois group is at most the degree of the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of the field $F[x]/(m(x))?

Comment: What do you mean $m(x)$?